# SQL date conversion adding significant time to Query - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have developed a large piece of coding, to get order information from our database. This has previously been working fine, capturing 1000s of lines of data in less than a second.

However, recently the specification has changed. We have moved from being Monday to Monday to the intention of running our orders from Saturday through Friday.

This has meant rewriting the code including case statements the following is an example:

```
*(Previous)*
,Case When To_Char(obd.due_date, 'YYYYIW') = To_Char(sysdate, 'YYYYIW') Then 'Current Week'

*(Now)*
,Case When TO_DATE(obd.due_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') BETWEEN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'WW')-2,'DD-MON-YYYY'))) AND (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'WW')+5,'DD-MON-YYYY'))) Then 'Current Week'
```

However I now lose the index on the fields due to conversion and thus the time for the data to be accessed has increased dramatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The *previous* calculation used an index? If you want to get all rows from the current week, why don't you some calculation based on `NEXT_DAY`?

Comment: Why `TO_DATE(obd.due_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` when it's already a date, and the `TO_DATE` function requires a string argument? However, I would be looking at the `where` clause rather than what appears to be part of the `select` list, which doesn't generally make any significant difference to the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that your "previous" calculation used an index (and it's used in a CASE, not a WHERE).

You should always try to get a *searchable argument*, i.e. calculation only on one side of the comparison:

```
WHEN obd.due_date >= next_day(trunc(current_date) , 'sat')-7
 AND obd.due_date < next_day(trunc(current_date) , 'sat')
```

should be what you want